# How to change opacity of cursor

Tags: javascript

I'm using a custom cursor that changes when the user hovers on different data-types. It is currently scaling up, but I also need to change the opacity to 0.7, I am unsure how to amend the following code to achieve this, although I assume it would be by adding to this line of code:

```
const keyframes = {
    transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${interacting ? 5 : 1})`
  }
```

**FULL CODE**

```
const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

const animateCursor = (e, interacting) => {
  const x = e.clientX - cursor.offsetWidth / 2,
        y = e.clientY - cursor.offsetHeight / 2;
  
  const keyframes = {
    transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${interacting ? 5 : 1})`
  }
  
  cursor.animate(keyframes, { 
    duration: 800, 
    fill: "forwards" 
  });
}

const getCursorClass = type => {
  switch(type) {
    case "video":
      return "fas fa-play";
      case "drag":
      return "drag";
    default:
      return "fas fa-arrow-up-right"; 
  }
}


window.onmousemove = e => {
  const interactable = e.target.closest(".interactable"),
        interacting = interactable !== null;
  
  const icon = document.getElementById("cursor-icon");
  
  animateCursor(e, interacting);
  
  cursor.dataset.type = interacting ? interactable.dataset.type : "";
  
  if(interacting) {
    icon.className = getCursorClass(interactable.dataset.type);
  }
}
```